# Calculate the exact weekday of a given date.

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

I've seen questions about calculating the exact weekdays on a given day, such as the AMC few years ago asking for the weekday that Charles Dicken's birth.

**For example, yesterday's Sunday, August 4, 2013.  On 1958, the Billboard Hot 100 was published for the first time in history.  How do I calculate the weekday for that day, August 4, 1958?**

How can we tell exactly what day would it be on a given day, calculated **without calculator/electronic aids in a timely manner**?

Comment: For a programming answer, see http://pastebin.com/jxeqXdZk it gives `Monday`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For example, if 8/4/2013 is a Sunday, then 8/4/2014 would be a Monday, 8/4/2015 is a Tuesday, and 8/4/2016 would be a Thursday (because it's a leap year).  Then let $0=$ Sunday, $1=$ Monday, etc, mod 7; do the adding and subtracting.
2. Or, [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=LO4cQiH3OUYC&pg=PA228&lpg=PA228&dq=scott%20flansburg%20calendar%20formula&source=bl&ots=yjzBftjvT-&sig=Ek75AGfzKXho_VPgztVECQxE-58&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tLX_UfjgEs_e4AOaqYCgDQ&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=scott%20flansburg%20calendar%20formula&f=false)'s a more "non-mathematical" way.

Comment: What's mod 7? I'm confused.

Comment: Nvm I got it man